# Why does my heroku application data keep resetting its data?

Tags: php, json, heroku

I have a Heroku application that edits and creates json files, I have noticed that after a few hours the data stored in the json files have been reset back to the default, more specifically the last state that I pushed. I am not totally sure about files it creates, I am testing that as I speak/type. The json files are of a normal/reasonable size, and the site could be totally inactive, and upon reloading the site its clear the json file has been reset.

I am using `get_file_contents()` and `set_file_contents()` as well as `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, and `fclose()`

There aren't any errors in the PHP, and like I previously mentioned, the site has been completely inactive when this happens.

So WHY TF do my files keep getting reset ?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
> the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
> shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
> filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
> container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
>
> In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a process known as "Cycling".

This is expected. If you are using Heroku Dynos and need to store files, the recommended approach is to use something like AWS S3 or Digital Ocean Spaces